# Spring XD - Duplicate messages with Kafka Message Bus

Tags: spring-xd

I’m trying to set up some streams and taps in Spring XD (1.2.1) using Kafka as the message bus and encountering some issues.

For testing purposes I have set up a Spring XD cluster with and Admin Node and two Container Nodes (although in production we would probably want at least 3 Container Nodes).

Ideally also we want all modules deployed to all containers for load balancing and fail-over purposes, although since module.*.count=0 does not work on with the Kafka message bus I’m doing this manually by defining module count 2 for each module.

The streams we want to create will send data through from a source to a sink and additionally send it to several counters.

For testing I'm using a http -> file stream.

Firstly I created

```
stream create httpfiletest --definition "http | file"
```

and deployed with

```
module.http.count=2,module.file.count=2
```

This creates both modules on each container and when I pass a message through it correctly sends the message to only one of the file outputs on one of the container machines.

I then created

```
stream create --name httpfiletesttap --definition "tap:stream:httpfiletest1 > transform | counter --name=httpfiletestcount"
```

When I deploy this without deployment properties it creates single transform and counter modules as expected and correctly counts the messages flowing through.

However if I deploy this with

```
module.transform.count=2,module.counter.count=2
```

(ie 2 transform and 2 counter modules, one on each node) each message gets counted twice.

Is this a bug? It looks like https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-3100 although I think this was raised with Rabbit as the message bus and its closed - is it possible this is still happening with Kafka as the message bus?

On Kafka the flowing topics are created:

```
                                        Partitions  Brokers
httpfiletest.0                              2       2
httpfiletesttap.0                           2       2
SpringXdOffsets                             1       1
tap_3Astream_3Ahttpfiletest.http.0          1       1
tap_3Astream_3Ahttpfiletesttap.transform.0  1       1
```

Is the difference in partitions relevant here?

As an alternative to using taps, I tried using a named channel ie

```
stream create httptotopic --definition "http > topic:mytopic"
stream create topictofile --definition "topic:mytopic > file"
stream create topictocounter1 --definition "topic:mytopic > counter --name=counter1"
stream create topictocounter2 --definition "topic:mytopic > counter --name=counter2"
```

And again deployed everything with a module count of 2. This not only gives duplicate messages in the counters but also in the file output (ie I get a message in the output file on each container.
Interestingly this seems to behave exactly the same if I use queue:myqueue.

In these scenarios XD does just seem to create one topic in Kafka which looks like what I want.

What is the expected behaviour here? Ideally what I want is to be able to place a message on a named channel and each distinct consumer ie file, counter 1 and counter 2 to pick up that message once even if there are multiple instances of them on different nodes. 
Is this possible? Should it be a queue or a topic?

Also it would be useful to have a bit more documentation on how streams, taps and named channels get mapped into queues/topics on Rabbit and Kafka. We are trying to design the streams to limit the amount of queues / topics created in the message bus, so it looks like the second approach (a topic instead of a tap) would be better in that regard.

Comment: I've now tested this against a Redis message bus as well, and I'm getting the same behaviour there - ie duplicate messages are consumed from taps and topics if I have more than one instance of the consumer. However it seems to behave as I want with a Rabbit Message Bus. It looks like https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-3100 was only fixed for Rabbit and not Redis or Kafka message buses.

Comment: https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-2115 seems to be a similar issue that again only mentions the Rabbit implementation

Comment: Ive raised https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-3613 for the Redis Message Bus version of this